# no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Seems obvious, so I overloaded the equality operator but it's still complaining:

```
template <typename T>
class FDataStreamSubscriber
{
    friend class FDataStream<T>;

private:
    FDataStreamSubscriber(FDataStream<T>* InStream)
        : ParentStream(InStream), LastGetTime(0.0f), SubscriberId(FGuid::NewGuid()) { }

public:
    bool GetIfNew(T& OutData);
    T* GetDataPtr();
    void Unsubscribe();

    friend bool operator==(const FDataStreamSubscriber& Left, const FDataStreamSubscriber& Right)
    {
        return Left == Right;
    }

    const bool operator==(const FDataStreamSubscriber<T>& Other) const
    {
        return this->SubscriberId == Other.SubscriberId;
    }

private:
    FDataStream<T>* ParentStream;
    FGuid SubscriberId;
    float LastGetTime;
};
```

Yet it's still giving me the error:

```
note: while trying to match the argument list '(FDataStreamSubscriber<T>, const FDataStreamSubscriber<T>)
```

If I changed the overload to that argument list, it says the operator is ambiguous. I can't win!

(See the rest of it here: http://pastebin.com/TUFwvpMr)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] as part of your question. Nobody should need to go to another web site to see it.

Comment: Which line is getting the error?

Comment: I don't see the need to have two equality functions.  The second one does everything you need.  The first one has a bogus parameter list.

Comment: After making some changes to produce a MCVE, the error I get is that it is ambiguous. Which is correct, since you defined two functions taking the same argument types.  The simplest fix is just to delete the first one, as paddy suggests

Comment: @paddy I think the parameter is correct, you can do that when defining a friend function inline in the class, and it means that it will generate a version for each instantiation with that instantiation's T as the template parameter

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was answered in comments